# Help identify the game that this board with marbles and a drawn pattern is used to play

Tags: identify-this-game

I found this home-made board amongst my father's possessions, it must use marbles but I have no idea how it is played. Can anyone throw any light on the subject?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it's a version of [Awithlaknannai](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/13766/awithlaknannai), or given the number of segments more accurately [Fighting Serpents](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/13656/fighting-serpents) (which is a translation of the name "Kolowis Awithlaknannai" anyway). It's an abstract game with rules similar to Checkers but, as you've noticed, a slightly odd-shaped board.

Comment: Thank you very much,  I used Dr. Google and found the rules for fighting serpents,  which as you said is a version of checkers.  Cheers. :-)

Comment: Great! You can mark my answer as correct by clicking on the check mark under the votes, that will help other people who come along later.